# Inserting a document into a document satisfying two conditions

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to insert a document(array) in already existing document.

I have gone through the topics on stack overflow for inserting document into a document. I have read about `$push` and have understood but my requirement is little different. So, what I want to do is - I want to add goals for a particular employee matching a particular project.

```
{
    "empCode": "001",
    "emapName": "ABC",
    "projects": [{
        "projectName": "P001",
        "projectMoreDetails": "projectMoreDetails",
        "Goals": [{
            "GoalName": "Goal1",
            "GoalMoreDetails": "GoalMoreDetails"
        }, {
            "GoalName": "Goal2",
            "GoalMoreDetails": "GoalMoreDetails"
        }]
    }, {
        "projectName": "P002",
        "projectMoreDetails": "projectMoreDetails",
        "Goals": [{
            "GoalName": "Goal1",
            "GoalMoreDetails": "GoalMoreDetails"
        }, {
            "GoalName": "Goal2",
            "GoalMoreDetails": "GoalMoreDetails"
        }]
    }]

}
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I add more goals for project 'P002' for employee code '001'?

Answer (score 0):

To find the matching document, use:

```
{empCode:"001", projects:{$elemMatch:{"projectName":"P002"}}}
```

While updating, you can use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to get the matched array element.

Your final update query would be something like:

```
db.emp.update(
    {empCode:"001", projects:{$elemMatch:{"projectName":"P002"}}},
    {$push:{"projects.$.Goals":{GoalName:"Upvote"}}}
)
```

Comment: Thank you Dushyant! I'll try it and update the same here.

Comment: @the_learner I've tried it on Mongo shell. If you're using java driver, syntax might differ a little bit.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I'm trying for its equivalent syntax in java.

Comment: Hi @DushyantBangal, I'm able to generate the find query through code but it isn't giving the desired result. I used the same query on NoSQL Browser to fetch the result but it's not working there also. The query generated from code is as follows - `12:05:10.911 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{ "find" : "ESPAUser", "filter" : { "empCode" : "JK004009", "projectAssessment" : { "$elemMatch" : { "paTitle" : "CCCHO" } } }, "limit" : 1`